# Elasticsearch Wildcard vs % in Query?

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the difference between these two queries and why would you use one over the other-

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "name": "*james*"
    }
  }
}

GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "%james%"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm having trouble finding documentation for the `%` version

Comment: Is there even a thing `% in Query`? Reference please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Comparison to query_string / field
>
> The match family of queries does not go through a "query parsing" process. It does not support field name prefixes, wildcard characters, or other "advanced" features. For this reason, chances of it failing are very small / non existent, and it provides an excellent behavior when it comes to just analyze and run that text as a query behavior (which is usually what a text search box does). Also, the phrase_prefix type can provide a great "as you type" behavior to automatically load search results.

You can find the above [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html)
Basically the match query you've included in your post will treat the `%` character as simple text, it doesn't have any special meaning.

Comment: My confusion was that in my sample I didn't use a real example. I'm actually doing search on urls where the wildcard `*url-part*` didn't match but `%url-part%` did. I see it's automatically tokenizing based on forward slashes `/`.